# SQL: Populating Column B where Column A has a match elsewhere in Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m somewhat of a newbie to SQL queries, especially anything containing logic, and although I've searched for hours finding the exact terms to search for is not easy in this case!  I have a relatively simple one, I’m sure:

A table has 2 columns, and each row contains data about a function in a program.  Some functions have a parent function associated (for grouping).  Column A is the unique function ID.  Column B indicates, when applicable, the parent function’s ID.  All parent function IDs are independent and valid function IDs that exist elsewhere in column A.

For reporting purposes I need to list the functions grouped by their parent ID, listing the parent function with the child functions.  I can easily report by parent function ID, but the problem is that a parent function does not know that it is a parent function because its column B is empty!

What I need to do is complete the value in Column B if it is empty and the function is referenced elsewhere as a parent function.

Otherwise stated, **for each row** that has a null value in Column B:

1. Take the value from column A
2. Check for the existence of that value in ANY row on column B
3. If there is a match, inject the value into column B (so that Column A and B have the same value)

What I have: (Query: `SELECT function_id, parent_function FROM functions`)

```
FUNCTION_ID   PARENT_FUNCTION   
4  
13            4  
79  
138           4
195
314           345
345
```

What I need to have:

```
FUNCTION_ID   PARENT_FUNCTION
4             4
13            4
79
138           4
195
314           345
345           345
```

Any Ideas? I can't wait to get more familiar with SQL!  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: do you really want the values in the table updated, or just displayed in your output?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this before.  New to the site!  No, I don't want the values updated, I just need to results updated - I'm pulling them into excel and using pivotcharts.

Comment: @Beth I have a follow-up question if any of you are interested [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822936/sql-excel-query-parameter-with-a-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE functions
SET parent_function = function_id
WHERE parent_function IS NULL
AND function_id IN (SELECT parent_function FROM functions)
```

This will set `parent_function` equal to `function_id` where it has not yet been set, and where it appears somewhere in the `parent_function` column.

If you don't actually want to modify the table data but still return values that you need, you can use similar logic like this:

```
SELECT f.function_id, COALESCE(f.parent_function, f2.function_id) as parent_function
FROM functions f
LEFT JOIN functions f2
  ON f.function_id = f2.function_id
  AND f2.function_id IN (SELECT parent_function FROM functions)
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I'm going to look up coalesce (as I said, really a beginner...).  This will allow me to get my report ready, and I'll keep customizing my pivot table as needed.  Thank you!

Comment: I have a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822936/sql-excel-query-parameter-with-a-join) if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can compare the two table using EXCEPT or INTERSECT

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx
```

more tutorials>:

```
 http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1327/compare-sql-server-datasets-with-intersect-and-except/
```

Comment: Very interesting tools indeed.  I can see how that could be handy for some things I have coming up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How's this look?

```
select distinct
t1.funx, t1.parent,
case when t2.parent is null then t1.parent
else t2.parent end as newparent
from 
tbl t1 left outer join
tbl t2 on 
t1.funx = t2.parent
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55d23/15/1)

Comment: Yes, this works, short and concise, and now I've learned how to use 'as' - great!  However I don't need the extra column, the solution by PinnyM is just what I need!